# Finding Extra String between two files in unix

Tags: unix

I need to find the string part which is different in two text files in unix and not the whole line. Any help how can i do this?

Comment: Start with `diff` to get the two lines; then do a character-by-character comparison of the two lines to get the part of the string that's different.

Comment: See also [`wdiff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/)

Comment: What do you mean by _find_? … visually highlight? … isolate? And what do you mean by _the string part_? For each difference, there may be _two_ string parts, one from each file. In what format do you want them presented?